# Low cost battery backup circuit for GSM Modem

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply

I am trying to build a schematic for a GPS tracker. The main target of the schematic is LOW COST. I have a problem with designing the power section. For a good, stable battery management and power path management there are ICs from TI, Microchip and other vendors. But those are costly and I am unable to use them in this schematic. The circuit will operate at 4V and the during bursts, the GSM module eats a max current of 1.8A. For this one, I have chosen LM2596 as the regulator and TP4056 as lithium charger. Now I need a cheaper way for power path. I have seen this schematic in one of the stackexchange's post. Can someone please tell me (with his/her practical experience), will be the switching fast enough so that my GSM module does not lack power and thus reboot? Also if anyone can give me a clue for a cheap SMD mosfet for this schematic.

So I am using LM2596 (in place of AP1117) and TP4056 (in place of MAX1555) for schematic below.

[image]

Or if anyone can suggest any other cheap alternate way for the power path switching, I am OK with that as well.

Comment: Like a datasheet define Vi range, Vout =4V? tolerance and Imin, Imax. You cannot begin to design untill you have all the specs. including transient response time and budget and volume. You must be new at this.

Comment: Hi @TonyStewartEEsince1975 Thank you for the comment, but I am not sure if you read my question with enough patience. I wrote that I have no problem with Input and Output voltages. I can use a 4.2V lithium to drive the GSM directly as well. So I have two distinct sources of power well designed. I am only having trouble with the POWER SWITCHING. Regarding transient response time, you can understand the priority as it is a GSM modem based circuit. Regarding budget, I have mentioned LOW COST..

Comment: Again. what is that "other Voltage range" and transient response time?  1us? 1ms? and VOut tolerance? This circuit wont work, but you MUST DEFINE specs first

Comment: Hi @TonyStewartEEsince1975, I don't have any particutr transient time in mind as long as the switching time gap can be bridged with a capacitor. VOut has to be within 3.8V-4.4V. Required continuous current 30mA, peak 1.6A. I don't know what do you mean by "Other Voltage Range". Please clarify.

Comment: What supplies the input power? = voltage range for your PchFET . Is it 3.8~4.4 or some other range.  Is it an Fe type LiPo? You must specify this./

Comment: Hi @TonyStewartEEsince1975 I did mention that, its LM2596. The GSM modem operates between 3.8V-4.4V, The battery will be a generic Lithium Plymer Lipo. Please note that, I am open for any other mechanism for the power switching circuit. It is not like that I must have to use the FET, it can be any other cheaper way as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75574/discussion-between-rakesh-mehta-and-tony-stewart-ee-since-1975).

Comment: Then add that to your question not in comments. There is no cheaper way other than shopping. RdsOn must not cause voltage drop (I*Rdson)